# Differences in Chrome on various OS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and i've met a very strange bug - my code works well on Mac OS, but doesn't work on Windows and Linux versions of Chrome. Versions are the same.

```
function captureAllScreen() {
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w) {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(w.id, {"format":"png"}, function(response) {
      var image = response;
      var url;
      chrome.tabs.getSelected(w.id, function(response) {
        url = response.url;
      });

      var viewTabUrl = [chrome.extension.getURL('app.html'),
                         '?id=', id++].join('');

      chrome.tabs.create({url: viewTabUrl}, function(tab) {
        var targetId = tab.id;
        var addSnapshotImageToTab = function(tabId, changedProps, tab) {
          if (tabId != targetId || changedProps.status != "complete") {
            return;
          };
          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(addSnapshotImageToTab);
          var views = chrome.extension.getViews();
          for (var i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
            var view = views[i];
            if (view.location.href == viewTabUrl) {
              view.twm_Draw.sendScreen(image, url); //Application-specific method
              break;
            }
          }
          window.close();
        };
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(addSnapshotImageToTab);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Update:
What i want to do with this code - is to take a screenshot and tab url and send it to my extension's page. When user clicks on my extension's icon - it opens a popup with two buttons, one of it fires this function.

In Mac Os everything works - this code takes a screenshot, tab url, opens new tab with my application and sends the data there. On Linux & Windows versions of chrome it doesn't send the data, after clicking the icon in the popup you just get a blank tab opened.

Comment: You probably want to describe what this is supposed to do/doesn't do to get a helpful answer.

Comment: I had a similar issue with multiple WebKit browsers. Chrome works and Android does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this part might be causing problems:

```
var url;
chrome.tabs.getSelected(w.id, function(response) {
  url = response.url;
});

//using url
```

The rest of the code should be wrapped into callback function, otherwise order of execution is not guaranteed.

Comment: sorry for delay, that helped a lot. by now i've totally rewritten the code, but your answer gave me a right way - the problem was in async code. Chrome for mac was a little bit faster and was able to deal with that task before i used this variable :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess it's only supported on Mac, whatever it does:

```
view.twm_Draw.sendScreen(image, url); //Application-specific method
```

I don't know about Unix but on Windows you can only get a screenshot using a NPAPI plugin like the Google [extension for screen capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg).